# SQL - Derived table joining

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query for a table in which the user can create multiple 'revisions' of a form. Currently we pass in the ID of the revision into the query to retrieve the values (as you can probably guess), which is fine - however I want to extend to also select the previous revisions rows (if they is a previous revision). Each revision has a number which is incremented when they create a new revision. Here's my query so far which doesn't seem to run (obviously the value 1,value 2 are the actual columns in my query)

```
SELECT ID, SageJobID, SageJobPK, DateID, Revision, StatusID, Value1, Value2
FROM   CVRs
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP(1) * 
                  FROM CVRs AS prevCVR 
                  WHERE (prevCVR.DateID = CVRs.DateID 
                    AND prevCVR.SageJobPK = CVRs.SageJobPK 
                    AND prevCVR.ID <> CVRs.ID) 
                  ORDER BY prevCVR.Revision DESC) AS 'PrevCVR'
WHERE        (CVRs.ID = @ID)
```

It seems I can't access the main CVR row I'm selecting from my join. Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS and version when asking SQL questions. I assume probably SQL Server from `TOP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an SQL Fiddle with a simplified version to give you an idea how you can solve it. SQL Fiddle Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94658/2)

That would be then about this

```
SELECT ID, SageJobID, SageJobPK, DateID, Revision, StatusID, Value1, Value2
FROM   CVRs
WHERE  DateId in    ( select dateid    from cvrs where CVRs.ID = @ID)
  and  sagejobpk in ( select sagejobpk from cvrs where CVRs.ID = @ID)
order by revision desc
```

**Edit:** I made another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f41ec/2) to also take the `DateId` aspect in but I got a question: Is it that all CV revisions that belong together must be of same `DateId` and `SageJobPK`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `OUTER APPLY` rather than `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT CVRs.*,
       PrevCVR.* /*TODO: Select desired columns*/
FROM   CVRs
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) *
                    FROM   CVRs AS prevCVR
                    WHERE  ( prevCVR.DateID = CVRs.DateID
                             AND prevCVR.SageJobPK = CVRs.SageJobPK
                             AND prevCVR.ID <> CVRs.ID )
                    ORDER  BY prevCVR.Revision DESC) AS PrevCVR
WHERE  ( CVRs.ID = @ID )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   a.ID, a.SageJobID, a.SageJobPK, a.DateID, a.Revision, a.StatusID, a.Value1, a.Value2
FROM   CVRs as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN  CVRs as b
on .DateID = b.DateID AND a.SageJobPK = b.SageJobPK AND a.ID <> b.ID
where a.ID = @ID  ORDER BY b.Revision DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get multiple most recent revisions is using the ranking functions:

```
select SageJobID, SageJobPK, DateID, Revision, StatusID, Value1, Value2
from (select CVR.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by revision desc) as seqnum
      from CVRs
     ) c
where c.ID = @ID and seqnum <= 2
order by revision desc
```

Seqnum orders the revisions, by assigning 1 to the most recent, 2 to the second most recent, and so on.